# Desktop turned gray in windows 10

Tags: windows

My Windows Screen is turned grey, i tried everything like updated drivers, windows restarted but it remains same. i don't know what happened. please help to resolve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of Screen Filter, i suppose by mistake you pressed **Window + Ctrl + C**

**Solution:** just press **Window + Ctrl + C** will resolve your problem.

Comment: Thank you @Juned Ansari. This is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

IF you opened the application color filter , close it .

Window + Ctrl + C